# Swift command hangs

Tags: swift, command-line

I'm trying to write a simple Hello World program, and run it from the command line. The code is simple.

```
import Foundation

print("Hello World")
```

When I run `swift HelloWorld.swift` the program just hangs, and outputs nothing, until I hit CTRL-Z to kill it. Any ideas on what the problem might be. It's such a simple example, I can't figure out what the problem is.

I know I'm putting in the right file name. When I put the wrong file name in it says "error: unable to invoke subcommand: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/swift-WrongFileName (No such file or directory)"

Comment: I did not. I just added it. now it looks like `#!/usr/bin/env swift

import Foundation

print("Hello World")` It still hangs when I run `swift HelloWorld.swift`

Answer (score 0):

It's hanging because it's a compiled language, we need to wait for the compiler to do its thing.

I use swift scripts differently with quick results:

1. Make sure you have the appropriate comment at the top

```swift
#!/usr/bin/env swift

import Foundation

print("Hello World")
```

2. From the terminal, run `chmod +x HelloWorld.swift` -- This allows the file to be executed.
3. From the terminal run `./HelloWorld.swift`

Comment: It will hang a moment while it compiles, but then you should see the output.

Comment: Okay, so I did this. I executed the file with ./HelloWorld. It hangs exactly the same as if I ran it with the swift command...

Comment: Interesting. Is your computer running smoothly otherwise?

Comment: If it's a long hang you may have something to work out on your machine, but Swift is a compiled language, so I would expect a very short delay.

Comment: Yeah. I'm building and running stuff in Xcode and Playgrounds just fine.

Comment: Is it faster the 2nd + time you run the script?

Comment: It seems exactly the same every time I run it. It immediately show a blank line, and shows nothing else. I've been running it for 3 minutes now.

Comment: Can you run `swift -v` in your terminal and tell me what your output is?

Comment: Yup. This is the output. `Apple Swift version 5.5.1 (swiftlang-1300.0.31.4 clang-1300.0.29.6)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.1.0
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/lldb "--repl=-Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -color-diagnostics -target-sdk-version 12.0"`

Comment: Are you on an Apple Silicon mac?

Comment: I am! Do you think that might be the issue? I have run into weird issues with it before.

Comment: It may be part of it.

Comment: I'm not sure how the configuration should differ, but my output is dramatically different. Swift is in my Xcode directory, not in my command line tools dir